# Probability of next item in normal distribution series given a series of values?

Tags: normal-distribution, stationarity, gaussian-process, z-score

Let' say that I have a normal dist data with x as time and y as the dependent variable. For all purposes, the data is normally distributed i.e. stationary. Now it would be clear that all my data regardless of time would normally distribute around mean and stddev with 50% lying where Z > 0 and 50% Z < 0. It would therefore follow that if I get a sequence of data where Z is < 0, then the probability that the item in the next sequence is Z > 0 is greatly increased. In other words, if say the sequence of observations is -0.5, -3, -1.3, then for every iterations where Z < 0, the probability of Z > 0 greatly increases. Is there a way to calculate this probability given the sequence?

Comment: Stationarity includes AR(1) models.  With AR(1) and positive $\rho$, several $Z$ below zero *increase* the probability that the next $Z$ is also below zero. If $\rho=0$, then it does not make any difference whether or how many previous $Z$ were below 0.

Comment: Could you give some context? If this is an equispaced [tag:time-series], please add that tag. Can you show us a plot, or the autocorrelation function?